# Calling "super (prototype)" from Java on an open Kotlin data DTO class

Tags: java, kotlin

I've got a Kotlin class, similar to

```
data open class MyDto (
var property: String? = null
// ...
)
```

and a Java class extending this class, similar to

```
class MySpecificDto extends MyDto {
    private String field; 
    // getter/setter for "field"
    public MySpecificDto(final MyDto prototype)
    {
        super(prototype);
    }
}
```

What is missing in Kotlin's DTO for the "super(prototype)" statement to compile?

Comment: Kotlin doesn't generate copy constructor for data class.

Answer (score 2):

`MyDto`'s constructor takes a single parameter of type String, and you are trying to pass it a `MyDto`.

I think you are looking for --

```
super(prototype.getProperty());
```

Data classes seem a like logical base for a hierarchy of DTOs.  Unfortunately, they do not play well with inheritance, so doing so is not a good idea. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467380/1904517).

**Update to address comment --**

For a Kotlin side solution, you need to remember Kotlin classes only allow for a single constructor.  For data classes, the format of that constructor is already defined, so you cannot just pass an object and have it work, or define a different constructor. Also, as noted by @bashor in comment to your original question, there is no copy constructor. You can, however, create a separate function to initialize your object if you want --

```
data open class MyDto (var property: String? = null //...) {
    fun init(dto: MyDto) {
        property = dto.property
        //... rest of the properties
    }
}
```

and the in your Java constructor call `init` instead of `super`.

```
public class MySpecificDto extends MyDto {
    private String field;

    public MySpecificDto(final MyDto prototype)
    {
        init(prototype);
    }
}
```

The caveat on this solution is that your data class *must* provide default values for all of its properties because there is an implicit call to the constructor with zero parameters.

Comment: super(prototype.getProperty()) passes just a single property to a constructor but I want to pass an entire prototype object that contains many properties. Also I'm looking for a solution in Kotlin code, not in Java code.