# Inheriting class with primary constructor

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a parent class as following,

```
interface ITask { }

open class Task(val targetServer: Server) : ITask { }
```

Then there a child inheriting it and overriding the primary constructor as following,

```
data class FileTask(val sourceServer: Server, targetServer: Server) : Task(targetServer = targetServer) {

}
```

This is throwing a compilation error in eclipse as

> Data class primary constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters

Removing the  `data` keyword from the class header will kill the error,  but I don't understand why.

Keeping the `data` keyword and adding `var` to the `targetServer`  gives another error

> 'targetServer' hides member of supertype 'Task' and needs 'override' modifier

Adding `override` to the `targetServer` to be `override var targetServer: Server` throws another error

> 'targetServer' in 'Task' is final and cannot be overridden

I need some help to understand these errors.

Comment: While not a duplicate per se, the answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444145/extend-data-class-in-kotlin is probably the most you will get.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Thanks, that looks helpful. But it basically says remove the `data` keyword, does not it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The initial error is because a data class can't have parameters in its primary constructor other than `val` or `var` properties. Removing the `data` keyword lifts this restriction.

It's been mentioned that data classes generally don't play well with inheritance. They're supposed to be used as simple data transfer objects, and aren't really suitable for participating in hierarchies, because it becomes hard to understand which properties are going to be considered in the implementations of the generated methods. Your best bet might be to not use them at all here.

For more about data classes and inheritance, [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/data-class-inheritance.md) is the proposal that was implemented in Kotlin 1.1.

---

To get back to the specific problem, if you really have to make this class a data class, you can mark the property in the base class as `open` and then override it in `FileTask`, like so:

```
open class Task(open val targetServer: Server) : ITask

data class FileTask(val sourceServer: Server, override val targetServer: Server): Task(targetServer = targetServer)
```

This basically hides the property declared in `Task`, and always accesses the property in `FileTask` instead.

I don't know what your exact requirements for your classes are, but one thing you could do to clean this up and make it a bit nicer would be to make `Task` and its `targetServer` property abstract, like so:

```
abstract class Task : ITask {
    abstract val targetServer: Server
}

data class FileTask(val sourceServer: Server, override val targetServer: Server) : Task()
```

This way you wouldn't have the unnecessary property (and backing field) in the base class, and you'd be forced to have a `targetServer` property in all the classes that inherit from `Task`. You could also take this a step further, and put the property in the `ITask` interface as well.

```
interface ITask {
    val targetServer: Server
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. the keyword `open` for the parameter is the solution but I wanted to understand. On the other hand, I think it is perfectly normal for DTO and POCO to inherit and polymorph

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I was struggling with the same issue and making my superclass abstract was not a solution. 
You just need to do the following:

change this

```
open class Task(val targetServer: Server) : ITask { }
```

to (Please note, I have made targetServer variable to open)

```
open class Task(open val targetServer: Server) : ITask { }
```