# Why Kotlin modifier 'open' is incompatible with 'data'?

Tags: class, inheritance, kotlin

I have a class:

```
open data class Person(var name: String)
```

and another class:

```
data class Student(var reg: String) : Person("")
```

this gives me an error that:

> error: modifier 'open' is incompatible with 'data'

if I remove data from `Person` class it's fine.

why kotlin open and data incompatible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html:

> To ensure consistency and meaningful behavior of the generated code, data classes have to fulfil the following requirements:
>
> - The primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter;
> - All primary constructor parameters need to be marked as val or var;
> - Data classes cannot be abstract, **open**, sealed or inner;
> - (before 1.1) Data classes may only implement interfaces.

So the main point is that data class has some generated code (`equals`, `hashCode`, `copy`, `toString`, `componentN` functions). And such code must not be broken by the programmer. As a result, data class has some restrictions.

Answer (score 18):

As the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes) states,

> - Data classes cannot be abstract, open, sealed or inner;

The reason why they cannot be inherited is that inheriting from a data class causes an ambiguity with how their generated methods (`equals`, `hashcode`, etc.) should work. See further discussion about this in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467380/4465208).

Since [Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#sealed-and-data-classes), the restrictions on data classes have been lifted slightly: They can now inherit from other classes, as described in detail in the related [proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/data-class-inheritance.md). However, they still cannot be inherited from themselves.

---

Note that data classes “only” provide the extra convenience of the automatic `equals`, `hashcode`, `toString`, `component`, and `copy` functions. If you don’t need those, then a class like the following still has properties with getters/setters and a constructor in a very brief form, and has no limitations on how you can use it with inheritance:

```
class User(val name: String, var age: Int)
```