# Kotlin - Data classes can be inherited

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to inherit a data class A from data class B. I know that this is not feasible in **Kotlin**.

**Question 1:**
Why is this not feasible?

**Question 2:**
What may be a solution for this?

Example:

```
data class A(val data1 : String)
data class B(val data2 : String) : A()
```

How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Comment: take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266735/4035036

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Kotlin modifier 'open' is incompatible with 'data'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266602/why-kotlin-modifier-open-is-incompatible-with-data)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444145/extend-data-class-in-kotlin
See the answer given by Andrey Breslav himself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend data class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444145/extend-data-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Question 1**

Data class contains some generated methods, like hashCode, equals, copy,... You could break those methods in class extending data class, but kotlin needs to guarantee that they work properly. That's the reason for making data class impossible to extend.

**Question 2**

The only solution for that, when you need two data class is to create one more abstract class and derive these two data classes from it. You need to notice that data class in kotlin create hashcode, equals and toString, and other methods based on primary constructor, and that's why you need to override fields from Base class in data class constructor.

```
abstract class Base(open val data1: String)

data class A(override val data1: String): Base(data1)

data class B(override val data1: String,  val data2: String): Base(data1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to do like below.

```
abstract class A(open val data1 : String) {}

data class B(val data2 : String) : A(data1)
```

Comment: And what if you want to instantiate class A?

Comment: It doesn't work. You have to pass param to `A` constructor.

Comment: When you do this but have to call the constructor from Java you get a "cannot inherit from final" compilation error, any idea of how to solve it?