# Kotlin data class inheritance

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, data-class

I have 2 Mongo collections that correspond to the following data classes: ArcadeSessions, ArcadeMarioSessions

```
data class PlayingSession(
    val sessionId: Int
    val sessionDescription: String
    val game: Game // Mario, GTA, ...
)

data class MarioPlayingSession(
    val numberOfJumps : Int
    val totalMarioScore: Int
    val level: MarioLevel
) : PlayingSession(...)


data class ArcadeSessions(
    val id: Int, // player ID
    val sessionHistory: List<PlayingSession>?
)

data class ArcadeMarioSessions(
    val id: Int, // player ID
    val sessionHistory: List<MarioPlayingSession>?
)
```

As you can see ArcadeMarioSessions basically contains a subset of ArcadeSessions for each player (let's not get into the "why").

It feels like a crime against humanity to write it like that (like completely different classes)
But for some reason, I can't get the data classes to play well with inheritance.

What is the correct way to write such a thing?

Comment: [This might help / explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467380/1712135)

Comment: @deHaar Saw this post, All I see is that data classes and inheritance does not go well together, question is what does, like whats the correct solution here?

Comment: That question contains several answers which may be used as alternative, such as `abstract class`es. I know this somehow violates the handyness of `data class`es. Maybe you can use that...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use inheritance, use composition:

```kotlin
data class MarioPlayingSession (
    val numberOfJumps: Int,
    val totalMarioScore: Int,
    val level: MarioLevel,
    val playingSession: PlayingSession
)
```

But [checking](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) whether the instances of `MarioPlayingSession` conforms `PlayingSession` will return false.
A bit cumbersome workaround for this is:

1. Define interfaces

```kotlin
interface PlayingSession {
    val sessionId: Int
    val sessionDescription: String
    val game: Game // Mario, GTA, ...
}

interface MarioPlayingSession {
    val numberOfJumps : Int
    val totalMarioScore: Int
    val level: MarioLevel
}
```

2. Implement them (using [Implementation by Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation) feature)

```kotlin
data class PlayingSessionImpl(
    override val sessionId: Int,
    override val sessionDescription: String,
    override val game: Game // Mario, GTA, ...
) : PlayingSession

data class MarioPlayingSessionImpl (
    override val numberOfJumps: Int,
    override val totalMarioScore: Int,
    override val level: MarioLevel,
    val playingSession: PlayingSession
) : MarioPlayingSession, PlayingSession by playingSession
```

Now both `MarioPlayingSessionImpl` and `PlayingSessionImpl` may be put into `List<PlayingSession>`